# Zend db - When should I quote to avoid sql injection?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am confused about when the framework automatically quotes and when it does not `quote` variables. For example, as far as I can tell, it does not quote on the `where` clause (unless you use an extra parameter?).

Is there a guide/cheat-sheet that references when we must manually `quote` in basic CRUD operations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the basic "rule of thumb" is the following:

- If you need to insert the value into a string, like that: `"SELECT * from TABLE WHERE value=$value"` you must quote it first.
- If you are using a placeholder, e.g. `$select->where('value = ?', $value');`, or an array of values such as `array('value' => $value)`, the framework will quote the value for you.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Little oversimplified, but good. You should quote 
1) any user input
2) anything that may contain SQL code

Comment: +1: To me, the wild-card is always the "order by" clause, which sometimes comes from user input. Perhaps you could augment the answer to address this aspect, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Never build the query string yourself, always let Zend_Db do it for you. I.e., don't specify your where clauses (and the like) by building the string yourself:

```
$where = 'id = ' . $_REQUEST['id'] . ' and thing = ' . $_REQUEST['thing'];
$select->where($where);
```

Instead do this:

```
$select
    ->where('id = ?', $_REQUEST['id'])
    ->where('thing = ?', $_REQUEST['thing']);
```